# windows authentication between host and VM

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, windows-server

I have created a VM (using Hyper V) that has Sql Server installed (win server os).

I want my host (or possibly another VM) to be able to access the SQL Server using windows authentication (sql server authentication works).

Can someone give me a jump start/guide for what I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To make this really work as you have planned you should have on active directory setup. So host machine and VM would be part of same AD domain.

I am very sorry but I don't have time create full instruction for this but in general steps would be:

1. Both VM's in same network with static IP settings
2. select local domain name, ex. test.local
3. setup AD & DNS on clean VM, this will be your domain controller (DC)
4. Create new VM for SQL server -server. Join in to test.local domain before installing SQL server
5. Install SQL server in SQL server VM using domain account

Comment: Thanks! How do I set this up? Should I create the active directory on the host or on a separate VM?

Comment: Are you using server or desktop operating systems in virtual machines ? If servers and you want to test "real" environment then I would create second VM with Windows Server OS and that would hold roles of AD-DC, DNS, and more if needed. I would then join your already created SQL server VM to this newly created local domain.

Comment: The VM has server OS (win server2012). I have created a second VM with win server2012 OS as well. But I need some guidance setting up AD-DC, DNS and so on.

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't have time to create full instructions for this but in general level you will have to do following:

Comment: Ok, any blog post/article I can start with?